# Move AfterBuild target to a .targets file

Tags: msbuild

I have a AfterBuild target that I would like to use for multiple projects in a solution.  Is there a way that I can put that target into a .targets file and reference the file in each project.

Below is what I tried which does not seem to work.

Project File:

```
<Import Project="..\debug.targets"/>
```

.Targets File:

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WebsiteDirectory>C:\Inetpub\wwwroot</WebsiteDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <output Include=".\**\*.dll" Exclude=".\**\obj\**" />
        <output Include=".\**\*.pdb" Exclude=".\**\obj\**" />
        <output Include=".\**\*.svc" />
        <output Include=".\**\*.xap" />
        <output Include=".\**\*.aspx" />
        <output Include=".\**\*.js" />
        <output Include=".\**\*.config" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <VirtualDirectoryPath>$(WebsiteDirectory)\$(RootNamespace)</VirtualDirectoryPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <copy SourceFiles="@(output)" DestinationFiles="@(output->'$(VirtualDirectoryPath)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\debug.targets"/>
```

`$(MSBuildThisFile)` = The current project file.
`$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` = The directory that contains current project file.

Relative paths in project files are difficult to use depending on what is invoking the project file.  Using msbuild directly and the relative path will resolve to the project file.  Use VS and the relative path will use the solution file as the base path.

Using `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` will force the relative path to use a pre-determined beginning path.  All you need to do is fill in the rest of the relative path.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fundamentally correct, but ensure that your Import statement is the last Import in the project file.

To verify that the target is being invoked correctly, run msbuild in diag mode from the command line and note the output regarding your target.

> msbuild myproj.proj /v:diag

Comment: That works from the command line but does not work when I build from visual studio.  Any idea what visual studio is doing differently?

Comment: @e82.eric - Right. I can't believe I missed that. Its because your relative path is incorrect. Try keeping the targets file in the project folder, or using a known path. When launching from the command line, the path resolves correctly, but for VS it starts from the solution folder.

Comment: I just tried changing it to the actual path.  <Import Project="C:\prompts_all\trunk\src\debug.targets"/> and still did not work from VS.

Comment: @e82.eric - Hmmm...try putting visual studio's msbuild into diag mode (Tools->Options->Projects And Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild oputput verbosity) and see what it says in the build window.

Comment: still nothing.  It actually works from the command prompt if I just type msbuild.

Comment: @e82.eric - Can you put the visual studio diag log up somewhere?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/prompts/downloads/detail?name=AfterBuildLog.txt&can=2&q=

Comment: @e82.eric - Its being run: `Target "AfterBuild: (TargetId:65)" in file "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "C:\prompts_all\trunk\src\Prompts.Web\Prompts.Web.csproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
Done building target "AfterBuild" in project "Prompts.Web.csproj".: (TargetId:65)`

Comment: it show it is overriding correctly when I look at the log from msbuild.  Overriding target "AfterBuild" in project "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" with target "AfterBuild" from project "C:\prompts_all\trunk\src\debug.targets".  http://code.google.com/p/prompts/downloads/detail?name=msbuild_afterbuild.txt&can=2&q=